# Onload change class Javascript

Tags: javascript

Finally designed a nice navigator for wordpress, but now the Links won't stay highlighted when click since it goes to different page. I need help with javascript code to change

```
<li class='last' id="meet">
    <a href='?page_id=7'><span>Meet Dr. Ayala</span></a>
</li>
```

to become this

```
<li class='active' id="meet">
    <a href='?page_id=7'><span>Meet Dr. Ayala</span></a>
</li>
```

I am sure I need `<body onload="onload()">` on the body tag. Can someone please explain how to fix this?

Edit: I managed to find a working function but needs to be converted to onload instead of clicking button

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
document.getElementById("meet").className = "active";
 });
});
</script>
```

Comment: If it goes to a different page, your DOM is reloaded. This will not work. The only thing you can do is add a class or id in the newly loaded page that you can use to decide which menu item will be highlighted.

Comment: how can i work around this. i would need to make an iframe for the body then? The pages i load are php and show as index.php?page_id=27, if it were a normal page i would know where to find it and edit it.

Comment: Let me make sure I'm correct, it sounds like you simply want to show the active link in your menu, so if your on page_id=27, check if that nav item exists and highlight it somehow. Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using php.
You could put your page number navigation in you body tag, or other solutions ..

url: `http://mydomain?page_id=7`

Pick op with `$_GET['page_id']`

Put something in your body tag

```
<body id="page_<?php echo $_GET['page_id'];?>">
```

Then in the JavaScript you can read th id of the body tag. Split out the number. Add some classes to your menu

```
<li class='menu_7'></li>
```

With the number you extract from the body tag id, you can target the menu class.

Hope that scenario will help you some. You can also add a static number in your page. That way you know for sure that you get a value. This is if your browser has to load a new page.

Other scenario could be an iframe or Ajax

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var nr = $("body").attr("id").split("_");
    $(".menu_" + nr[1]).addClass("active");

});
```

Comment: how do i make this work on load instead of clicking button `<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
document.getElementById("meet").className = "active";
  });
});
</script>`

Comment: Where does button come back? I do not see a button tag. And your script will run "onload" with the jQuery "document.ready" statement

Comment: this is a code i got from internet. i wanted to replace the button with onload function. and i  already found solution, but  cant  vote on my self :(

Comment: I ended up using this code, made several if statements to my liking. Thank you

Comment: Most welcome ;-). Many ways to do things with creativity. Good luck and cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it working
    `<script>
    function onload() {
           document.getElementById("meet").className = "active";
        }
        window.onload = onload;
    </script>`

Comment: Yes, it will work. You do make me smile on that. 
You can also do window.onload = function(){// code goes here }

Answer (score 1):

you can use jquery to add/remove class

e.g

```
$("#meet").addClass("Active");
$("#meet").removeClass("Active");
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go, it will find the current link, and jump back to its parent and give it a class of active.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var urlBits= document.URL.split('/');
   var current = urlBits[urlBits.length-1];
   $('a[href="'+current+'"').parent('li').addClass('active');
}
```